# LINQ to SQL - CASE statement with subquery

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am having trouble trying to represent the below SQL (which returns the results I want) in LINQ:

```
select 
    case r.CategoryID
    when 2 then
        case r.PrimaryRecord
            when 1 then r.RecordID
            else (select RecordID from Record where RecordGroupID = r.RecordGroupID and PrimaryRecord = 1)
        end
    else
        r.RecordID
    end
    as RecordID
    , r.FooID
from Record r
where 
    r.FooID = 3
```

Each row in the Record table has a unique RecordID. Multiple RecordID's could be associated with a RecordGroupID for CategoryID 2, but only one of them will have the PrimaryRecord field value of 1.

Given the below table of data, my desired output is RecordID = 1, FooID = 3, i.e. the RecordID for the given RecordGroupID that is the PrimaryRecord, but the FooID for the given row that matches my Where clause.

```
RecordID    RecordGroupID    PrimaryRecord    CategoryID    FooID  
1           1                1                2             1
2           1                0                2             1
3           1                0                2             3
```

I appreciate the SQL itself probably isn't the most efficient SQL in the world but it was the best I could come up with.

If anyone could help me create the LINQ statement to represent this query that would be great.

Comment: What is `t.PrimaryRecord`? `t` is not defined in your query anywhere.

Comment: @Yuck - apologies, was a typo. Fixed now.

Comment: @Yuck - just wanted to say thanks for the answer that you posted and deleted. Although I rewrote the SQL it was very useful to see how it could have been done if I didn't have the option.

Comment: NP. The accepted answer is better than the one-for-one LINQ statement I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't really need the case in the original query. Try something like:

```
var matchingRecords = from r in Records
                      where r.FooId = fooId && r.CategoryId == catId && r.RecordGroupId == groupId
                      join r2 in Records on r.RecordGroupId == r2.RecordGroupId && r.CategoryId == r2.CategoryId && r2.PrimaryRecord 
                      select r2;
```

**Edit:** added `CategoryId` in join, assuming `RecordGroupId` is only unique inside a category.

Comment: Thanks! Funnily enough I had just figured out how to rewrite my SQL query to do pretty much what your LINQ statement does. The query didn't really feel right in the first place but haven't written any for 12+ months.